# why $p(V_0)$ does not even contain $b_0?$

Tags: algebraic-topology

The map $p : \mathbb{R}_{+}  \to S^1$  given by the equation  $p(x)=(\cos 2 \pi x , \sin 2\pi x) $ is surjective and local homeomorphism   .

Munkres  say that but $p$ is not a covering map because of the
behavior of the point $b_0 = (1, 0)$. A small $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $b_0$ has an inverse image
of small neighborhoods $V_n$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ which are mapped homeomorphically
onto the neighborhood of $b_0$, but $V_0 = (0, \delta)$ is not; **$p(V_0)$ does not even contain $b_0$**.
So $p$ is a local homeomorphism, but not a covering map (because of its failure to
evenly cover an $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $b_0$).

**My confusion** :  why $p(V_0)$ does not even contain $b_0?$

**My attempt** :   Diagram from the Munkres  book

[image]

from the diagram $p(V_0)$  contain $b_0$  i,e $b_0=(1,0)$  is lie  inside $p(V_0)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image $p(V_0)$ is not $U$ (the bold part in the picture).

$p(V_0)$ is an *open arc* of the circle which has $b_0$ at its boundary (so it does not contain $b_0$).

[image]